# Server side access data for smartGWT rpc

Tags: java, rest, smartgwt

On the server side I want to know how to access data used in an RPCRequest from SmartGwt.

Here is the SmartGwt client code:

```
  private void update() {
        RPCRequest request = new RPCRequest();
        request.setData("RPC text from client");
        request.setActionURL("/Empi-MT/resources/empi/update");
        request.setContentType("text/xml");

        RPCManager.sendRequest(request,
            new RPCCallback() {

                public void execute(RPCResponse response, Object obj, RPCRequest request) {
                    SC.say("Response from the server:" + obj);
                }
            });
    }
```

Here is the RESTful java server code .

```
    @POST
    @Consumes("text/xml")
    @Produces("text/xml")
    @Path("/update")
    public String update() {
        return "We got to here";
    }
```

This trivial code works fine, but now I need to know how to access the data that was put into the RPCRequest.   How do I do that in the server code?

Thanks,

Comment: Actually I have already implemented the CRUD that I need relating to this particular REST service and the related ListGrids.  but I want to add a couple of methods to extract some related data from the Web service.  I would prefer to use SmartGwt RPC so I can examine the RPC calls in the SmartGWT console.  What I don't know is how in the Server Java Code I extract the data that was put into the RPC request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look like you may be heading in the wrong direction; if this "update" operation is a CRUD operation on some object, you want to using DataSources - take a look at the QuickStart overview of Data Integration, focusing on RestDataSource.

http://www.smartclient.com/releases/SmartGWT_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf

Also you seem to be starting down the road of using generated REST services, this is almost always wrong - see this FAQ:

http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8159#aExistingRest

Finally if this really is not a CRUD operation, you want to set useSimpleHttp on the RPCRequest, and then the docs for this property explain the different ways data can be sent.

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/rpc/RPCRequest.html#getUseSimpleHttp()

Comment: This is not a CRUD operation.  I'm actually adding a couple of utility methods in addition to the CRUD which I have already implemented.  Specific details about how I got this working based on you answer is that on the client side I added the following code:   

    request.setUseSimpleHttp(true);
    request.setHttpMethod("POST");

The payload comes through to the server java method as a String argument (XML encoded).  And, the details of the RPC calls to my utility methods are visible through the RPC tracking feature in the SmartGwt developer console.

many thanks,
Jay